# How can I display a React Native Victory chart component in a dynamic HTML file for exporting it into a PDF?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, export-to-pdf, victory-charts

How can i show a JSX component (react native victory chart) in dynamic HTML file ?(this html file is a page that contain charts and details,then html file should convert to PDF file that user could export his/her charts in html)

```
const handleExportPDF = ()=>{
const htmlFile = `
<html>
<body>
<section>
<VictoryChart /> //for example show that chart here with extra detail
</section> 
</body>
</html>
`
sharePDF('htmlfile','export file name') //this libray convert html to pdf then share that with base64
}
<View>
<VictoryChart />
<Button title="export as pdf" onPress={handleExportPDF}/>
</View>
```

i tried to put component in this html file , from VictoryChart docs all i found there is this solution to ScreenShot that component ( but problem is how to screenshot a chart with many types ( diffrent views with daily , weekly , ...  and i need all of them )
with this screenshot method i should mount a component with all chart and take screen shot from all of them
i need better way to show a chart in direct html

Comment: @KJ - chart is static but i dont know how to show a <Component /> in html